# Smooth convex function with both attainable global minimum and global minimum at infinity

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex and $C^1$. Is it possible that it simultaneously has two global minima, one is attainable at a finite point $x_0$ and the other is only attained at infinity (just like the global minimum of $1/x$ over $(0,\infty)$ is attained at $+\infty$)?

---

The background of this question is that I want to minimize a convex and continuously differentiable function with Lipschitz continuous gradient. If I know $f$ has an attainable global minimum, and I use gradient descent method with small enough constant stepsize to solve this problem, is it possible that the iterates diverge to infinity? If yes, can you give an example? If no, then can you prove the iterates are bounded? Note that the initial point can be any point.

---

The known result in classical textbook shows that the function value converges to global minimum, i.e., $f(x_k)\to f(x^*)$, where $x^*$ is any global minimum of $f$. Also, if the global minimum is not attained, then it is easy to construct counterexample like $f(x)=e^{-x}$. Also, if we know $f(x)$ is coercive, then the iterates must be bounded. However, if we only know it is convex and assume there exists $x_0$ attaining global minimum, then it is completely nontrivial whether the iterates are bounded or not.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "not attainable minimum".

Comment: @Meowdog Like $f(x)=e^{-x}$, the global minimum of it is at $x=\infty$. Maybe I do not put it in a very rigorous way, but such phenomenon is what I mean.

Comment: Okay, this is called infimum. Did you know that local minima are global minima for convex functions? What does this tell you?

Comment: @Meowdog Yes, I know for convex function all of local minima is global, but there could exist multiple global minimum. I have edited my question so that it becomes a rigorous math problem.

Comment: If a convex function has 2 minima, what can we say about points between them (i.e. the convex combinations of the minima)?

Comment: @paperskilltrees I know what you mean, we can show all global minima $x^*\in\mathbb{R}^n$ forms a path connected set, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: Right: all points on the segment connecting two minima are also minima. Now move one end-point to infinity, so that to match what you described in the 1st paragraph of your question. Alternatively, consider a line passing through the "attained" minimum, and the "minimum at infinity", and then consider the ray from the "attained" minimum towards the "minimum at infinity". I believe this answers your question in the 1st paragraph by further characterising all functions that have the described property.

Comment: @paperskilltrees Thanks for your reply. I think for the first paragraph the answer is that it is impossible to have such a situation. However, the real issue is in paragraph 2 and 3.

Comment: @William It's possible if you drop "only" in "... and the other is _only_ attained at infinity...": a constant function being an example.    
Paragraphs 2-3 are a separate question. Maybe you will find the answer on the wiki page for Pseudoconvex Function.